# Session issue in Wildfly 10.1.0

Tags: java, session, cookies, wildfly, session-cookies

I have two web appplications
1. test.war
2. birt.war

I set cookies in http response header for birt url

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(GlobalConstants.JSESSIONID, request.getSession(false).getId());
cookie.setPath("/birt");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Then I open birt url with appropriate url parameters in javascript like

```
window.open(url);
```

But the next request from birt I get have new JSESSIONID. This works in JBoss6 AS.

I am able to see the cookies in developer console

```
**Request 1**
http://192.168.10.7:8080/test

Cookies are 
Response Cookie :
JSESSIONID : 
value = 9G6bzvsF-ijbynGTmbWp7Ml4E5KFVHiEPlSflh16
Path = /birt

**Request 2**

http://192.168.10.7:8080/birt

Cookies are 
Response Cookie :
JSESSIONID : 
value = **xrLqLb5-8Vvqlkk2GKyapqwJZm5dJnyvFQOia9IM.node1** // new cookie
Path = /birt

Request Cookie :
JSESSIONID : 
value = 9G6bzvsF-ijbynGTmbWp7Ml4E5KFVHiEPlSflh16
Path = /birt
```

Also I tried adding in both wars in jboss-all.xml but even that does not work.

```
<shared-session-config xmlns="urn:jboss:shared-session-config:1.0">
        <session-config>
            <cookie-config>
                <path>/</path>
            </cookie-config>
        </session-config>
</shared-session-config>
```

Comment: What is the question?? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @LestyánMihály From http://192.168.10.7:8080/test i am opening http://192.168.10.7:8080/birt in javascript before that I set cookies in httpresponse but on http://192.168.10.7:8080/birt response header I get different JSESSIONID. I am expecting the same JSESSIONID in the response header of the birt app

Comment: Could you please share your wars? I'll run some tests...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that your deployment model is different from the one Undertow supports:

> Undertow allows you to share sessions between **wars in an ear**, if it is explicitly configured to do so. Note that if you use this feature your applications may not be portable, as this is not a standard servlet feature.
>
> In order to enable this you must include a shared-session-config element in the **jboss-all.xml file in the META-INF directory of the ear**

Please referece https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Web+(Undertow)+Reference+Guide

Comment: I have different wars directly deployed. I don't have ear.

Comment: Exactly. From documentation session sharing is possible only when wars are deployed as single ear deployment unit.

Comment: Is there any other way?. I want to deploy it in war file.

Comment: I don't see the issue here: EAR is a ZIP archive having you WAR and JAR files in root and meta information folders. I believe the requirement for EAR is to make sure that you are fully aware of the consequences and will not include some other app by accident.

Comment: If we assume that you have 2 independent apps, then tightly coupling them by session sharing is a bad design. Use message queue, shared state service or simply persist state in database.

Answer (score 3):

Here we share the same session between wars in Wildfly 10.1 by configuring **single-sign-on** property in the undertow subsystem (domain.xml / standalone.xml). Like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener max-post-size="1073741824" name="default" socket-binding="http"/>

        <host alias="localhost" name="default-host">
            <single-sign-on path="/"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    .
    .
    .
</subsystem>
```

And in jboss-web.xml, inside the war files, we set the disable-cross-context property to false:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/test</context-root>
    <disable-cross-context>false</disable-cross-context>
    .
    .
    .
</jboss-web>
```

If this doesn't work, please provide your war files.